# How to know when and by whom last publish was made?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

For example we have 2 teams which share one demo server. They make publish several times a day. How can I know when (date and time) and by whom (member name) the last publish was made? May be there is some Visual Studio option or TFS setting to get publish notifications?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get a build timestamp.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Read the linker timestamp from an executable.
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime RetrieveLinkerTimestamp(String strFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            //Open file
            string filePath = strFileName;
            const int c_PeHeaderOffset = 60;
            const int c_LinkerTimestampOffset = 8;
            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            System.IO.Stream s = null;

            try
            {
                s = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                s.Read(b, 0, 2048);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (s != null)
                {
                    s.Close();
                }
            }

            //Get timestamp
            int i = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(b, c_PeHeaderOffset);
            int secondsSince1970 = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(b, i + c_LinkerTimestampOffset);

            //Convert to date/time
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            dt = dt.AddSeconds(secondsSince1970);
            dt = dt.AddHours(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(dt).Hours);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in RetrieveLinkerTimestamp", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I could open directory for publish I will just check date of dll manualy. But I don't have acess to publish directory. So I need some option or tool to get information about latest build through TFS.